# C# Outlook Interop Access to Contacts

Tags: c#, outlook

At work everyone has a UserID and an e-mail address.
I can get the e-Mail of the UserID using Outlook.
For example I have a UserID: `myUser1`. 
Using Outlook and putting into the `To` Section `myUser1` inside and pressing `ctrl + k`, the according e-Mail address will be added.
Now I want to implement that into my C# Form. I have hundreds of UserIDs and want to send a Mail to each of them.

So, how can I access the Contacts with known UserIDs(Outlook Initials)?

Comment: Did the existing related questions on this site (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/4210703/87698 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/45032958/87698) help you? If no, why not?

Comment: I have checked them, but I don't know how to Access the UserID there? Like the ctrl + k shortcut. Which Method do I use?

Comment: Are you using Outlook Object Model to talk to the locally installed copy of Outlook? Or are you using the Graph API?

Comment: I am using the outlook object. But I don't find the initials. I want to access the global address and from there I want to find the email address corresponding to their initials.